# Convertion Error

Tags: java, php, android, magento

I am trying to call a web service from Android client on the Magento Store.
I have good success till now but have little problem.

I want this array to be converted in to appropriate java Object.

```
$arrProducts = array(
array(
    "product_id" => "1",
    "qty" => 2
),
array(
    "sku" => "testSKU",
    "quantity" => 4
)
);
$resultCartProductAdd = $proxy->call($sessionId, "cart_product.add", 
                                        array($shoppingCartId, $arrProducts));
```

The Above php code has been taken from [**`here`**](http://www.magentocommerce.com/wiki/doc/webservices-api/api/cart#example_php)

What I have tried.

```
Object []addtocart=null;
Log.i("Product Id ", Utils.product_list.get(rowid).getp_Id());
Object[] productdetails1=new Object[]{Utils.product_list.get(rowid).getp_Id(),2};
//Object[] productdetails2=new Object[]{productdetails1};
Object param1[]=new Object[]{Utils.shoppingCartId,productdetails1};
Object param[]=new Object[]{Utils.sessionId,"cart_product.add",param1};
try {
    addtocart=(Object[])client.callEx("call", param);
} catch (XMLRPCException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

But it results into error like the :

```
org.cws.magentoAnd.xmlrpc.XMLRPCFault: XMLRPC Fault: One item of products do not have identifier or sku [code 1022]
at org.cws.magentoAnd.xmlrpc.XMLRPCClient.callEx(XMLRPCClient.java:228)
at org.cws.magentoAnd.ProductModule.productdetails$CartFunctions.doInBackground(productdetails.java:245)
at org.cws.magentoAnd.ProductModule.productdetails$CartFunctions.doInBackground(productdetails.java:1)
at android.os.AsyncTask$2.call(AsyncTask.java:185)
at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(FutureTask.java:306)
at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:138)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1088)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:581)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:1019)
```

I would be happy if someone having dual knowledge of php and Java would help me to solve this Issue.

Comment: Can you share your wsdl, it will be helpful.

Comment: @sharadendusinha :View this. http://www.magentocommerce.com/wiki/doc/webservices-api/api/cart#cart_product.add  
Actually i have not generated the wsdl,i am using the Magento's inbuilt methods.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok,getting some Ideas from [**`@ sharadendu sinha's`**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12470731/convertion-error#answer-12472476) Answer, I have made a `Associative Array` like thing in Java that would get the required result.

The code is as below.

```
Map map = new HashMap();
map.put("product_id", 1);
map.put("quantity", 1);
Object[] productdetails1=new Object [] {map};
Object param1[]=new Object[]{Utils.shoppingCartId,productdetails1};
Object param[]=new Object[]{Utils.sessionId,"cart_product.add",param1};
try {
    Object addtocart=client.callEx("call", param);
    Log.i("Out Put of Adding", addtocart.toString());
} catch (XMLRPCException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

If you check the stack trace you will see 
>
 One item of products do not have identifier or sku

So the mapping for sku is not getting found. it is also obvious as to why the mapping is not getting found. As the php object is an associative array. The java counterpart for the same is Map.

Now if I was making RPC (WebService based) call using a library like ksoap I would use somthing like PropertyInfo(http://ksoap2.sourceforge.net/doc/api/org/ksoap2/serialization/PropertyInfo.html) to do the mapping between property name and its value. So it depends on the client side library that you are using.

In your code you are using

```
addtocart=(Object[])client.callEx("call", param);
```

It is not eveident from the code snippent as to what is the type of client, so I was not able to guess as to what is the library that you are using, but what ever the library try and look out for some utility classes on the lines PropertyInfo

Comment: Hey,,i am using XMLRPC library.Can you please help me to  sort it out the mapping for XMLRPC library?

Comment: Is there any way to associate the properties and its value ?

Comment: could you please give the name of the *.jar file that you are using there are number of libraries that are currently available now.

Comment: +1 for your help,,it was from there I got the idea..thanks..See the correct answer that I have posted here.Thanks once again.